# Request for help numpy array syntax

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using a template-script to learn data analysis in using numpy and I don't understand this syntax. There exist two arrays `dist_data` and `dataArray`, `l` is a loop-dummy-variable (as in `for l in range(0,k):`)and I don't understand the content, specifically the purpose of separation by `,` in the second parenthesis `[l, self.dataArray.shape[1]-1]` because I am assuming that it represented a column of `dist_data`

`dist_data[dist_data[:,-1].argsort()][l, self.dataArray.shape[1]-1]`

Comment: You should write down the code you are working with. Thus other people can understand better what you are dealing with

Comment: firstly, change that loop variable to something sane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dist_data[dist_data[:,-1].argsort()][l, self.dataArray.shape[1]-1]
```

`dist_data[:,-1]` last column of 2d `dist_data`.  Sort on that and get the indices

So `dist_data[dist_data[:,-1].argsort()]` is `dist_data` sorted on the last column.

`[l, self.dataArray.shape[1]-1]` is just an indexing on a 2d array; the `l` row, and the `self...` column.  It looks like the column that corresponds to the last of `self.dataArray`.

So in sum - sort `dist_data` on the last column, and pick the `l'th` row, and some column.

Comment: Thank you for the response; I was able to use it to create and manipulate a sample np.array to figure out the purpose of this syntax